# Pyplot animation memory leak with FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory-leaks

I'm using pyplot 2.0 with the FuncAnimation for streaming serial data to a figure where it is continously updated.

For the FuncAnimation to work you have a **Figure**, **Func** (function to call at each frame), and **Frames** (Source of data to pass func and each frame of the animation)  fairly simple I thought and it does animate the way I would expect.

However the figure continues to chew up memory until it crashes the Raspberry Pi even though I have the **blit** flag set to optimize the drawing and only render the new data points.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Setup plotting, one figure and two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)#,sharex=True)
g_line = ax1.plot([],[],'g')
r_line = ax1.plot([],[],'r')

lines = []
# Add each line to o ur tuples of lines to be plotted
lines.extend(g_line)
lines.extend(r_line)

# Data plotting function, this is call from the animation
# Each data element is in the data list being returned below
def plot_data(data):
  x1 = data[0]; y1 = data[1]; 
  x2 = data[2]; y2 = data[3]; 

  lines[0].set_data(x1,y1)              # Audio - green
  lines[1].set_data(x2,y2)              # Audio thresh - red
  return tuple(lines)

def data_gen():
  my_list = []
  my_list2 = []

  # Main infinite loop for processing of serial data
  while True:
    # Grab input RX serial data
    (my_list, my_list2) = readUART(serReader)

    yield my_list, my_list2
  #end while

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_data, data_gen, interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

I have tried to clear the figure after each iteration but that severly slows down the rendering.

Is there some memory i'm not aware of that is holding onto it each time it plots even when the plotting fills the figure completely and moves off the screen?

**Note -** I ran a memory profiler on the entire program minus the plotting and just did it on the while TRUE loop and the memory didn't move past 55mb the entire time I let it run.

Comment: Did you also run the memory profiler on the entrire program (including plotting), is it significantly different?

Comment: I did and it continued to grow up into the hundreds of mb's until the pi ran out of memory so the program auto crashed.  Without the plotting its constant around 55mb.

Comment: def data_gen is my generator function that needs a while TRUE so it keeps yielding back resuts for the plot. http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation

Comment: What does readUART return? It seems to be a tuple of lists; how long are those, are they getting longer over time? I have problems to see how the 2-tuple can later be indexed with data[3], that should throw an error.

Comment: ReadUART returns two lists and each will grow as there is more data each time.

Comment: So the problem may then simply be that those lists become too large at some point. You might then decide not to read in *all* the data from the device, but only the last few points or so.